# How to format geoJSON file from python dump using python-geojson?

Tags: python, geojson

Im trying to create a features array using python and python-geojson. I appended some features such as Polygon with working coordinates. However when I dump, there is no indentation in the geoJson file. It is all on one line and mapbox does not accept the data.

f

```
features = []
poly = Polygon([[(2.38, 57.322), (23.194, -20.28), (-120.43, 19.15), (2.38, 57.322)]])


features.append(Polygon([[(2.38, 57.322), (23.194, -20.28), (-120.43, 19.15), (2.38, 57.322)]]))
features.append(Feature(geometry=poly, properties={"country": "Spain"}))


feature_collection = FeatureCollection(features)

with open('myfile.geojson', 'w') as f:
   dump(feature_collection,f)
f.close()
```

Thats how the output looks. It should be indented instead of clustered like that.

{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[2.38, 57.322], [23.194, -20.28], [-120.43, 19.15], [2.38, 57.322]]]}, {"geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[2.38, 57.322], [23.194, -20.28], [-120.43, 19.15], [2.38, 57.322]]]}, "type": "Feature", "properties": {"country": "Spain"}}]}

Answer (score 1):

Add an 'indent' param to your dump() call:

```
with open('myfile.geojson', 'w') as f:
   dump(feature_collection, f, indent=4)
```

It's strange, however, that a piece of code won't accept JSON that is all on one line.  It's just as much valid, legal JSON.  That's a bug in that code.  Using the 'indent' param is usually done just for human readability.

Comment: `geojson.dump` doesn't seem to support `indent`. The important information is to use `json.dump` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Backing up a bit, there are three types of GeoJSON objects:

1. Geometry
2. Feature
3. FeatureCollection

A `Feature` includes a `Geometry`, and a `FeatureCollection` includes one or more `Features`. You can't directly put a `Geometry` inside a `FeatureCollection`, however, it needs to be a `Feature`.

In the example you've shared, your `FeatureCollection` includes one `Feature` and one `Geometry` (in this case, a `Polygon`). You'll need to convert that `Polygon` to a `Feature` before adding it to a `FeatureCollection`.

Not sure if you intended to have two identical polygons, but your example would need to look something like this to output valid GeoJSON:

```py
features = []
poly1 = Polygon([[(2.38, 57.322), (23.194, -20.28), (-120.43, 19.15), (2.38, 57.322)]])
poly2 = Polygon([[(2.38, 57.322), (23.194, -20.28), (-120.43, 19.15), (2.38, 57.322)]])

features.append(Feature(geometry=poly1, properties={"country": "Spain"}))
features.append(Feature(geometry=poly2))

feature_collection = FeatureCollection(features)

with open('myfile.geojson', 'w') as f:
   dump(feature_collection,f)
f.close()
```

Indentation shouldn't matter here.

You can read more than you ever wanted to know about the GeoJSON spec at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946.

Comment: Answer does touch the topic of formatting / indenting the output, does it? Also, in the code the big question is if `dump` refers to `json.dump` or `geojson.dump` which seem to have different underlying formatters.

Comment: @bluenote10 I think the actual problem the OP is having is caused by invalid GeoJSON data, rather than any indentation or formatting issues. I answered in this way to show why it is invalid, and how to fix it.